# Select only direct children of parent div, not all sub divs

Tags: javascript

So I'm trying to select 3 divs in my parent element. With my current code the result is I get 162 nodeLists back, instead of just the 3 main divs in that parent element.

The page code looks like this (simplified):

```js
var parent = document.querySelector('.parent');

var wantedChildren = parent.querySelectorAll('div');

console.log(wantedChildren);
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="wantedChild">
    <div class="unwantedChild">
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="unwantedChild"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="wantedChild">
    <div class="unwantedChild"></div>
    <div class="unwantedChild"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="wantedChild">
    <div class="unwantedChild"></div>
    <div class="unwantedChild"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So the divs are just examples. The entire code on the page is way bigger.

I just want those 3  divs.

Does anybody know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var wantedChildren = parent.children;
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/children

Answer (score 1):

You can use direct child selector

```js
const wantedChildren = document.querySelectorAll('.parent > div');

console.log(wantedChildren);
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="wantedChild">
    <div class="unwantedChild">
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="unwantedChild"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="wantedChild">
    <div class="unwantedChild"></div>
    <div class="unwantedChild"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="wantedChild">
    <div class="unwantedChild"></div>
    <div class="unwantedChild"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```